Why are jobTitles and links always longer than companyName and jobLocation?
Every time I run my code the lengths of the lists are different than the last time. And every time jobTitles and links are longer than companyName and jobLocation. I'm not sure how to fix this. All of the lists should be the same length. I'm just not sure what is happening that they are alwasy different lengths, not always by the same amount either.
Even if there is just a way I can add a blank entry when it can't pull the data that would be fine. I just don't know how. I have tried and can't get it to work.
import hrequests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import csv

####################
## INDEED SCRAPER ##
####################

# Creates the CSV in Write Mode
with open('Indeed_Jobs.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)

#Creating Lists for info
jobTitles = []
companyName = []
jobLocation = []
links = []

#Creates list of URLs
URLs = ["https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=IT+Entry+Level&l=United+States&from=searchOnHP&vjk=55e3c7e5e7a919c9", 
        "https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=development+entry+level&l=United+States&from=searchOnDesktopSerp&vjk=996b270bd119f225",
        "https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=user+experience+entry+level&l=United+States&from=searchOnDesktopSerp&vjk=4fc6a443fd7c11df",
        "https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=ux%2Fui+experience+entry+level&l=United+States&from=searchOnDesktopSerp&vjk=254dcd8c33926527",
        "https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=data+entry+level&l=United+States&from=searchOnDesktopSerp&vjk=bd4fd45f0feb91c2"]

for url in URLs:

    #Connecting to Indeed and reading HTML
    target_url = url
    head= {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,lt;q=0.8,et;q=0.7,de;q=0.6",
    }
    resp = hrequests.get(target_url, headers=head)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')

    #Finds all items in list
    for div in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'css-dekpa e37uo190'}):
        #Pulls job title
        for span in div.find_all('span'):
            jobTitles.append(span.text.strip())
        #Pulls link to job
        for a in div.find_all('a'):
            links.append("indeed.com" + a.get('href'))
        #Pulls company name
    for div in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'company_location css-17fky0v e37uo190'}):
        for span in div.find_all('span',{'data-testid': 'company-name'}):
            companyName.append(span.text.strip())
        #Pulls job location
        for divLocation in div.find_all('div', {'data-testid': 'text-location'}):
            jobLocation.append(divLocation.text.strip())


    # Changing the heading on the CSV depending on which URL was searched
    if url == "https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=development+entry+level&l=United+States&from=searchOnDesktopSerp&vjk=996b270bd119f225":
        additional_row = ["Development - Entry Level"]
    elif url =="https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=it+entry+level&l=United+States&from=searchOnHP&vjk=bf9a1055e66b240c":
        additional_row = ["IT - Entry Level"]
    elif url == "https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=user+experience+entry+level&l=United+States&from=searchOnDesktopSerp&vjk=4fc6a443fd7c11df":
        additional_row = ["User Experience - Entry Level"]
    elif url == "https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=ux%2Fui+experience+entry+level&l=United+States&from=searchOnDesktopSerp&vjk=254dcd8c33926527":
        additional_row = ["UX/UI - Entry Level"]
    elif url == "https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=data+entry+level&l=United+States&from=searchOnDesktopSerp&vjk=bd4fd45f0feb91c2":
        additional_row = ["Data - Entry Level"]
    else:
        additional_row = ["Title Not Found"]

    # Blank Row to make formatting nice
    blank_row = ['']



print(len(jobTitles))
print(len(companyName))
print(len(jobLocation))
print(len(links))

#
#   # Open the CSV file in append mode
#    with open('Indeed_Jobs.csv', 'a', newline='') as file:
#        writer = csv.writer(file)
#        # Write the header and blank rows for formatting
#        writer.writerow(blank_row)
#        writer.writerow(additional_row)
#        writer.writerow(blank_row)
#
#        # Write jobs to the CSV
#        df = pd.DataFrame({'Job Title': jobTitles, 'Company Name': companyName, 'Location': jobLocation, 'Link': links})
#        df.to_csv(file, mode='a', header=True, index=False)


What is hrequests ?

maybe some elements are empty - and problem is you search elements in separated for-loops. You should use one for-loop to work with elements which keep one title, one link to job, one company name. And this way you can catch if some element is missing and you can put empty value in its place. And keep them as nested list instead of separated lists - data = [ (job, title, link), (job, title, link), (job, title, link) ]

I run your code and always get the same number of jobs, names, locations and links - I can't reproduce your problem. But still I would use only one for-loop - first I would search all <li> or <div class="slider_container"> (or <div data-id="slider_container"> and later I would search jobs, names, locations and links in every elements (not using another for-loop with soup.find...)

Your code works for me without different lengths of lists but to make sure I would use only one for-loop with soup.find_all() - to find all frames with offers - and later use only find() to search single job, company name, location, link` in every frame
    # finds all frames with offers
    for frame in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'slider_container'}):
    #for frame in soup.find_all('div', {'data-testid': 'slider_container'}):

        div = frame.find('div', {'class': 'css-dekpa'})
        
        # job title
        item = div.find('span')
        text = item.text.strip()
        jobTitles.append(text)
        print('job title   :', text)
        
        # link to job
        item = div.find('a')
        text = "indeed.com" + item.get('href')
        links.append(text)
        print('link        :', text)

        div = frame.find('div', {'class': 'company_location'})

        # company name
        item = div.find('span',{'data-testid': 'company-name'})
        text = item.text.strip()
        companyName.append(text)
        print('company name:', text)
        
        # job location
        item = div.find('div', {'data-testid': 'text-location'})
        text = item.text.strip()
        jobLocation.append(text)
        print('job location:', text)

        print('-----')


This is super strange. I copied my code from this post, worked like a charm. I then tried coping my original code from VS code into a new file, I have the issue.
The code is identical, I mean I copied my code from VS code to Stack Overflow, but for some reason coping it from my Stack Overflow post fixed the issue?

Well I posted that and now it doesn't work anymore

if you have both versions in two files then you can use tools like Meld to compare them - maybe it will find differences.

sometimes code may looks the same but may use different indentations - spaces and tabs - and this can make difference for Python (but not for human who looks at the code). And Stackoveflow could replace tabs with spaces and fix some problems.
